# Stopping a job programmatically inside the reducer code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Suppose I detect something in the input key/value in the reducer code, what code should actually run so that the reducer doesn't continue anymore, any emitted records at the output is written to the output file and the job stops with no more further reduce happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a job might not be a good idea.
But if you need it, one way would be to create your own exception class, perhaps extending either `InterruptedException` or `IOException`, and throw that exception whenever the condition arises when you want to quit.

Your exception class may be as follows:

```
Class QuitReducerException extends InterruptedException {

      //Parameterless Constructor
      public QuitReducerException() {}

      //Constructor that accepts a message
      public QuitReducerException(String message)
      {
         super(message);
      }
}
```

And in your reduce method, you may use it as follows:

```
@Override
 protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
      ...
      if(<condition to quit happen>){
          throw new QuitReducerException("Quitting reducer due to some specified reason");// You may add details of the reason you are quitting and this will be available in the job logs (in stderr)
      }
      ...
  }
```

**PS:** This would not ensure that outputs emitted by the current reducer would be committed to output files. Also any other reducer which wasn't finished will not commit the files. While the reducers which were already complete, would have already committed their outputs.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case where multiple reducers must be running on your hadoop cluster. So even if you detect something wrong in the input and try to stop it, you are not sure that the state is consistent(i.e. no records are processed once wrong input is received) because multiple records may be processed by multiple reducers in parallel.

So I dont think it is a good idea to stop the job.

Comment: +1, I agree it isn't a good idea, but in certain cases it might be required.